# Refer to a specific object instance in a complex RequireJS app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am building a not-so-small app using BackboneJS and RequireJS and I sometimes find myself wanting to have access to some objects (let's say: a certain instantiated view #1), from an another object which is far in the app's object hierarchy tree (e.g. a sub-sub-view of a completely unrelated instance of view #2).

Is there a good practice to achieve this?? in a way that:

a) Doesn't involve passing parameters across different objects on object creation

b) Doesn't break the "no-globals" paradigm that seems to rule RequireJS good practices

In my opinion, option a) makes code very hard to handle as the app gets bigger. And difficult to understand, because you need be constantly tracing where all those parameters lead you to.

And option b (using a global var) is all-or-nothing. If I use one global, I can just use one big global which namespaces all my app and I would be missing one of, I think, most important RequireJS features.

Answer (score 0):

In my apps i have maximum 3 level of hierarchy. I'm passing options while i initialize views, like below.

```
var view = new ChildView({dropdown: this.dropdowm});
```

and accessing like this in ChildView.

```
this.options.dropdown
```

And this is the prescribed way in Backbone.js. Sometimes, for properties like "Customer ID", "Product ID", i don't pass them to each level in hierarchy. I initialize a global object called `App` and i attach those properties into `App` like below.

```
var App = {};
App.cutomerId = "12";
```

So i can access customer id like `App.customerId` in anywhere in my app.

But i don't attach views / models directly into `App`. Because, it is easy to break your app by accessing your views / models anywhere. Other developer can access them anywhere in your app. And it would become more complicated when you debug for some errors, because he might have used that model across all your app. This is more complicated than tracing `this.options`. So you should be aware about what things you should include into global scope.